# JQuery binding on('click') to multiple selectors not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-selectors

*Please see update below*

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnClose, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

It fires when I click `#btnClose`, but not the **jQuery UI** close button in the top right corner.

I also tried flipping it around and I get the same results.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close, #btnClose', function () {});
```

Here is the HTML for the jQuery UI close button:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
</button>
```

**update** The button is in an iframe.  This must be the problem.  Any creative ideas?

Here is what I have currently:

```
       function closeDialog() {
           alert('Closing');
               //this works fine
       }

       $(document).on('click', '#btnClose', function () {
           closeDialog()
               //this never fires
       });

       window.parent.$(document).on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function () {
           closeDialog();
       });
```

The second one is not working still.  Keep in mind the script is part of the iFrame, so it needs to access the selector from the parent.  The weird part is that I'm using window.parent.$() to do other things without problem.

Comment: Can you update this fiddle to reproduce your error? http://jsfiddle.net/Us7R9/

Comment: Apparently not, it works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/Us7R9/2/

Comment: It must be because the content of the modal is an iframe.  I'm trying to get the fiddle to mirror the issue, but I can't load a local div into the iframe... http://jsfiddle.net/Us7R9/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is crazy, but it works.

```
$('#btnClose').add(parent.$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')).on('click', function () {
    closeDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A closing round bracket is missing in your original code. JS is very sensitive to brackets. The calls will be incorrect if brackets are missing and your code will not work.
I have fixed your code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnClose, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Same applies to the second bit of code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close, #btnClose', function () {}
);
```

In both cases, there are three parameters to `.on` function: two strings and callback function.

It may be a copy/paste error, but it easily might happen to be "the" cause of the issue.

Comment: No problem. These are easy to overlook when you have no compilation step to do the checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact in any way with the content's of an `iframe`, if it's not in the same domain. (there's [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage), but this is another topic).

If the iframe is from the same domain it's easy, instead of:

`$(document)`

use

`$("#iframeID").contents()`.

Comment: The script is in the iframe.  I'm trying to use window.parent, but still having no luck so far.

Comment: So you place this `jQuery` in the iframe (your website) and want to access the parent (which is on the same domain) ? So you use `$(window.parent)`?

Comment: $(window.parent).on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close') did not work either.

Comment: parent.$(".selector") works and led me to the complete answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

You may be dealing with [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The security policy will prevent mangling with elements from another site or protocol.

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm using window.parent to manipulate the modal in other ways.  All these files are part of the same project on the same site/server.